# How to filter nested array using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

This is my Array (http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=cc51a12581667055781639b586fa6e15):

```
[
  {
    "documents": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "isSelected": true,
        "status": "good"
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "isSelected": false,
        "status": "good"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "documents": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "isSelected": true,
        "status": "bad"
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "isSelected": false,
        "status": "good"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "documents": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "isSelected": true,
        "status": "verygood"
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "isSelected": false,
        "status": "good"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "documents": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "isSelected": false,
        "status": "good"
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "isSelected": false,
        "status": "good"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to write condition using _.lodash.
This condition has to return TRUE if in array is at least one `Selected` document with `Status` other than `good` or `verygood`

---

Based on array from above.
http://prnt.sc/de3gx9
You can see on the screenshot that in array is an object with:

1. isSelected
2. Has other status than `good` or `verygood`

If in my Array is at least one object (with isSelected = true, and status = bad (or any other than good or verygood).
Then I want to see RESULT: **TRUE**

```
 function checkStatusInArray() {   
       var data = [....]; // this is my array

       var isDocumentSelectedWithWrongStatus = _.some(data, { isSelected: true, status: !"good" || !"verygood" });
       // So if in array are some items with isSelected = true and status != good || verygood, then isDocumentSelectedWithWrongStatus = TRUE

       return isDocumentSelectedWithWrongStatus; 
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify the condition to filter?

Comment: I added filter, because I thought that gonna be easier with less number of objects

Comment: I want to see only bool reasult. If there will be item with isSelected = true and status = bad, worst, badly or any except: good or verygood.

Comment: Please check code from edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lodash's [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#flatMap) to pluck the documents into one collection and then use [**some**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#some) on the collection:

```js
var data = [{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":true,"status":"good"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]},{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":true,"status":"bad"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]},{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":true,"status":"verygood"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]},{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":false,"status":"good"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]}]

var selectedButNotGood = function(document){
  return document.isSelected && 
    document.status != "good" && 
    document.status != "verygood"
}

var result = _.chain(data)
              .flatMap('documents')
              .some(selectedButNotGood)
              .value();

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without lodash - [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside `Array#some` and a predicate (the predicate can be inlined as anonymous function), if the predicate returns, the result will be truthy:

```
function checkData(data, predicate) {
  return data.some(function(item) {
    return item.documents.some(predicate);
  });
}

function predicate(document) {
  return document.isSelected && 
    !(document.status === 'good' ||
    document.status === 'verygood');
}
```

```js
function checkData(data, predicate) {
  return data.some(function(item) {
    return item.documents.some(predicate);
  });
}

function predicate(document) {
  return document.isSelected && 
    !(document.status === 'good' ||
    document.status === 'verygood');
}

var data = [{
  "documents": [{
    "name": "a",
    "isSelected": true,
    "status": "good"
  }, {
    "name": "b",
    "isSelected": false,
    "status": "good"
  }]
}, {
  "documents": [{
    "name": "a",
    "isSelected": true,
    "status": "bad"
  }, {
    "name": "b",
    "isSelected": false,
    "status": "good"
  }]
}, {
  "documents": [{
    "name": "a",
    "isSelected": true,
    "status": "verygood"
  }, {
    "name": "b",
    "isSelected": false,
    "status": "good"
  }]
}, {
  "documents": [{
    "name": "a",
    "isSelected": false,
    "status": "good"
  }, {
    "name": "b",
    "isSelected": false,
    "status": "good"
  }]
}];

var result = checkData(data, predicate);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Are you sure that is correctly? It seems that it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Well when I was trying to use it in this way: `var b = deepFilter(data, predicate);` where data = my array, then this function deepFilter assigned to `var b` all arrays.

Comment: Code snippet returns 3 objects. I wanted to check whether  in `Data` is `selected` document with `status` other than `good` or `verygood`. If there is at least one. I wanted to see TRUE. Nothing more.

Comment: Maybe this filter was a bad approach. Anyway this filter return me objects where `isSelected=true` So only first 3 records of Array in this case. However it give me nothing. Because there are still documents with status other than `good` or `verygood`. I'll try to explain you in edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over them and create your own custom array.

```js
var d = [{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":true,"status":"good"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]},{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":true,"status":"bad"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]},{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":true,"status":"verygood"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]},{"documents":[{"name":"a","isSelected":false,"status":"good"},{"name":"b","isSelected":false,"status":"good"}]}]

var statusList = ['good', 'verygood']
var r = d.some(function(o) {
  return o.documents.filter(x => !statusList.includes(x.status) && x.isSelected).length > 0;
});
console.log(r)
```